# Text recommendation for introduction to linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I have learned linear algebra before, but with my right brain - basically nothing left, so, anyone can recommend me good textbook so I can learn it again?

The text should subject to the conditions listed below.

Currently, I have found, from other questions asked here, *Linear Algebra Done Right* by *Sheldon Axler*, and *Advanced Linear Algebra* by *Steven Roman*.

It will be used for preparing an exam, (Don't take me wrong, I like math), and the later one has an "advanced" in its name, so I'd better pass it.

The first one is good, but got a little greedy, want a better one~

Video course is OK too.

*Conditions*:

- It should be a introduction, but not too elementary.
- Don't begin with linear equations, matrices or determinant. (The one I used did so, these stuffs are so boring, and the experience is really terrible.)
- It should cover: (I don't really believe this condition can be satisfied, so, the more the better)

  - Matrices (inverse, rank, Jordan canonical form etc.)
  - Determinant
  - Kernel space, dimension of vector space and quotient space
  - Linear map and its relation with matix
  - Other "common topics" a LA introduction text should cover, and have some "famous results". (Don't let me define "common topics", I assume the answerer knows so much about LA that he knows which topics should be covered, and which should not be. Same for the "famous results" :-)
- Don't care real world applications and numeric computation.
- Do it in a more "mathematical"/modern/abstract way, i.e., every term is formally defined, proofs are rigorous, etc..
- Prefer formal proofs than intuitive ones.
- Prefer "proof-like" proofs than those in a computation style.
- Having good exercises is a bonus.
- Doesn't have, or has little contents about group, ring, etc.. (I have limited time)
- Clear written.

Thanks.

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: Also, Rotman's book may not be the best choice for exam prep. There are a lot of things in it that you won't be tested on in a standard undergraduate linear algebra exam. It's written with a different kind of reader in mind.

Comment: Also, because this is my personal crusade: The left-brain/right-brain stuff is a myth.
(http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-myths/201206/why-the-left-brain-right-brain-myth-will-probably-never-die)

Comment: Have you looked at Finite dimensional vector spaces by Halmos?

Comment: @lhf It is not, that one focus on application.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra* by **Seymour Lipschutz**. It is full of solved exercises which you can find out what is going on in Linear algebra intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

The notes by this professor, Jose Figueroa-O'Farrell, are excellent. This is a link to his LA set:

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/MT3/LinearAlgebra.pdf

Comment: I think it's still doing it in a traditional way, and use too much  matrices/computation in proofs (at first glance). Thanks.